# Jumpy div resizing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why my selection div is jumping around on mousemove.

I have this jsbin that I've been using to develop this document section selection page.

http://jsbin.com/IGuNEmi/7/edit

What is supposed to happen is, when you click down, the top and left of the selection div is set to the `offsetX` and `offsetY` of the `mousedown` event, then the `mousemove` event's `offsetX` and `offsetY` are used to determine what to set the div's height and width css properties to with jQuery. When you let the mouse up over the document's div, it should change the border to green, and report the X, Y, Width, Height to the coordinates `span`.

What is happening is that while you move your mouse around, the width and height seem to be changing to a smaller height and width, and sometimes, when you let the mouse up, the height and width are set incorrectly.

I'm not sure what is causing this jumpiness on the selection div, and was wondering if anyone knew what might be causing this, and how I should fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinct the `event` like this:

```
var mouseDown = false;
var mouseDownOffsetX, mouseDownOffsetY, mouseUpOffsetX, mouseUpOffsetY;
var sel = $("#selection");
$(function(){
  $('#documentPage').mousedown(function(eventA) {
    if(!mouseDown){
      mouseDownOffsetX = eventA.offsetX;
      mouseDownOffsetY = eventA.offsetY;
      sel.css('left', mouseDownOffsetX);
      sel.css('top', mouseDownOffsetY);
      sel.width(0);
      sel.height(0);
      sel.css('border', '1px solid red');
      eventA.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    }
    mouseDown = true;
  }).mouseup(function(eventB) {
    mouseUpOffsetX = eventB.offsetX;
    mouseUpOffsetY = eventB.offsetY;
    sel.css('border', '1px solid green');
    var width = mouseUpOffsetX - mouseDownOffsetX;
    var height = mouseUpOffsetY - mouseDownOffsetY;
    mouseDown = false;
    $("#coords").html(mouseDownOffsetX + ", " + mouseDownOffsetY + ", " + width + ", " + height);
  }).mousemove(function(eventC) {
    if(mouseDown){
      sel.width(eventC.offsetX - mouseDownOffsetX);
      sel.height(eventC.offsetY - mouseDownOffsetY);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you actually try this yourself? It doesn't help anything. The div is still jumpy when resizing.